# Gradient descent for linear regression takes too long to converge

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I began to study machine learning and stuck on one issue.

My implementation of this method (both in MATLAB and C++) converge in 1 500 000 iterations, and I can not understand why. I found the method [implementation in Python](https://github.com/mattnedrich/GradientDescentExample/blob/master/gradient_descent_example.py), and the algorithm converged in 2000 iterations. Under converged I understand that he gave almost the same answer as obviously the correct method.

Preliminary data are not processed in any way. Can you explain me please, is this normal number of iterations, or I just made a mistake in the algorithm?

The cost function used and its partial derivatives:

[image: cost]

MATLAB code

```
%y=t0+t1*x
learningRate = 0.0001;
curT0 = 0;
curT1 = 0;
i     = 1;

while (i < 1500000)
    derT0 = 0;
    derT1 = 0;
    for j=1:1:N
         derT0 = derT0 + (-1/N)*(Y(j) - (curT1*X(j) + curT0));
         derT1 = derT1 + (-1/N)*X(j)*(Y(j) - (curT1*X(j) + curT0));
    end
    curT0 = curT0 - (learningRate*derT0);
    curT1 = curT1 - (learningRate*derT1);
    %sprintf('Iteration %d, t0=%f, t1=%f',i,curT0,curT1)
    i = i+1;
end
```

P.S. I tried to increase the "learning Rate" variable but in this case, the algorithm diverges and comes in huge numbers.

Comment: You have no other stopping condition aside from `while (i < 1500000)` so of course this will run for `1500000` iterations because you have not told it not to...

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I'm not exactly asked. I mean why in fewer iterations, it does not converge to the exact solution (or very close to it). For example like the one in Python for 2000.

Comment: post the Python code to compare...

Comment: Here is the code https://github.com/mattnedrich/GradientDescentExample/blob/master/gradient_descent_example.py

Comment: well for starters the Python code multiplies by `(-2/N)` and your code multiplies by `(-1/N)`, why the discrepancy?

Comment: Because different cost function. My is multiplied by (1/2*N), on Pythone is  multiplied by  (1/m). When we take the derivative the deuce is not reduced, and goes into the numerator.

Comment: Well what happens if you use their cost function? Or if you alter their code to use your cost function?

Answer (score 2):

The [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) depends on three things:

- the initial solution `[curT0,curT1]` (the starting point from which to begin the search)
- the learning rate (how big a step to take in the direction of the gradient)
- the number of iterations

If you start far off and make small steps it will take you many iterations to reach the solution. If the steps are too big, you can miss the solution by stepping over it. Also the search could get stuck in local minima depending on where you started from in the search space..

Also you can specify other stopping criteria like a tolerance (a threshold which if crossed, stops the iterations). Your current code will always loop the maximum number of iterations (1500000).